# DDD and Microservices - data flow and structure

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I'm trying to create a simple blogging platform and at the same time learn more about DDD and Microservices, so I wanted to ask you about two advises in this context:

1. One of the business rules I assumed in my project is that only users in roles `Publicist` and `Administrator` are able to create posts, but posts created by `Publicist` have to be approved by `Administrator` first before they go public. In my understanding this is a part of a `Posts.Domain`, so in `Post` aggregate (and at the same time entity) I encapsulated changing the post's status into methods like `SetPublishedStatusBy` that take `User` (requestor) data as parameters and evaluate above rule (+ create domain events). However now I'm having some doubts whether information about requestor is really a part of the `Posts.Domain`. Maybe requestor should be evaulated in a different place, like `Posts.API` or some other service and `SetPublishedStatus` would be then called without parameters after it is already done?
2. Let's stick to above context. Despite `Posts` microservice, I'm also developing independent `Users` microservice responsible for storing the users and providing some tools for `Administrator` to manage them. What would be then the proper data flow when a user wants to publish a new post? I'd imagine this in a following way:

- Client sends `PublishPost` command with a post ID to the gateway
- Gateway authenticates user from HTTP request (probably done via cookie with JWT)
- Gateway sends a `PublishPost` command to `Posts` microservice
- `Posts` microservice calls `Users` microservice to get relevant user data from DB
- `Posts` microservice retreives post from DB by ID
- All business rules are evaluated through the `Posts.Domain` and status is changed to `Public`
- `Posts` microservice updates DB if everything goes fine and notifies Gateway that sends `Success` HTTP response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts ...

For DDD, you're best served by taking guidance from the Ubiquitous Language of the domain when discussed with a domain expert.

The term "SetPublishedStatusBy" probably wouldn't come up in that discussion.

I think the most likely outcome of that discussion would be:

- An Administrator and **publish** a *post*.
- A Publicist can **submit** a *post* that an Administrator must **approve** before it is published.
- An Administrator can **approve** a *submitted post* that has been Submitted by a Publicist, which will result in the *post* being published.
- An Administrator can **reject** a *submitted post*.

My Post aggregate would then end up looking something like:

```
class Post
{
    void Submit()
    {
        this.Status = Submitted;
    }
    void Publish()
    {
        this.Status = Published;
    }
    void Approve()
    {
        if (this.Status != Submitted) throw "This post is not pending approval.";
        this.Status = Published;
    }
    void Reject()
    {
        if (this.Status != Submitted) throw "This post is not pending approval.";
        this.Status = Rejected;
    }
}
```

When creating the post, the UI would either be calling Publish or Submit in your API, depending on the context.  The API would then check that current user can perform the requested Publish or Submit.

Two other options:

1. Introduce an Aggregate called PostRequest that Publicists have permission to create and only create a Post when that is approved by an Administrator.
2. If you want the rules to be more dynamic, i.e. a user just hits 'Publish', whether they are a Publicist or an Administrator and then the outcome is either a published post or a submitted post depending on the rules of the day, then you'd want an orchestration / saga / task layer in between your API and the Aggregate which can interact with User service to decide whether the the first call to the Posts service should be a "Submit" or a "Publish".

Comment: Thank you. I'm a one-man army so far, so unfortunately I cannot rely on a domain-expert until I become one :-)

Comment: So I assume that the responsibility of checking the right role before making changes would be moved to Application Layer (service) and tracking who and when made changes would belong to Infrastructure Layer or Unit of Work in particular, right? Also, how would you handle updating the content of the Post? I think I would still need to add a User concept to a Domain as an Author and Editor as they are conceptually different than tracking from Infrastructure Layer (e.g. even though Administrator approved the Post and will be kept as a last User that made changes in DB, he didn't edit the content)

Comment: Yes, I would implement authorizations in the application entry point (the API), but it would be perfectly normal to pass details such as current user to the domain and infrastructure implementation as properties of your entities.